# Tinder's Algorithm to loading photos in Objective-c. Replicating it with Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, algorithm, parse-platform

That's a totally theoretical question, but here we go. I'm building an App that's similiar to Tinder in the aspect that will be loading people profile photos in a row and the user can like them or not. Well, I'm using Facebook's Parse in the server side, but I'm far from getting the speed of Tinder when loading the photos. In my very rudimentar algorithm, every time one person is liked or disliked, the app load a new name and a new photo, and this takes something like 1 or 2 seconds to happen. So, I was wondering if someone nows a better way of loading a serie of photos to show them to the user.

I'm thinking in loading 5 photos when the app starts and when the user is dismissing the first one, the 6th will start downloading. This would give me some time advantage but i don't think is the way Tinder is doing.

Any clues!?

Thank you guys!

Comment: You could stick [a proxy](http://mitmproxy.org) in your network config so you can see what requests Tinder is making, or at least their number and frequency if they are encrypted. You could also bundle multiple images into a single request (e.g. zip them) to reduce network latency and overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how Tinder is doing it, but I think you are on the right track. You can use Parse's query constraints to get the behaviour you're aiming for.

You could do something like this (using Swift):

```
//When the app starts
var query = PFQuery(Classname: "YourClassName")
query.limit = 5 //Get the first five profiles


//When the user swipes away a profile
//Assuming you have stored the profiles in an array called, say, "userProfiles"
var query = PFQuery(Classname: "YourClassName")
query.skip = userProfiles.count //Skip the results already loaded
```

Of course you'd have to complete the queries to fetch the correct users.

If you find that users swipe through the profiles too quickly, you could play around with the values of `.limit` and `.skip`.

I'm not an expert in algorithms, but I'd suggest a good starting point is to find out, on a user specific basis, the average time between swipes and comparing that to the average time it takes to load your data. I'm sure someone with more experience in writing algorithms can give you a much more specific answer however.

Comment: That's a incredible start point man! Thank you!! I didn't knew about this .limit and .skip functions in PFQyery! Do you know if they work in objective-C too? I still haven't find time to learn the All new Swift syntax! Thank you again!

Comment: They certainly do! The syntax for them is actually exactly the same as in swift, just do `query.limit;` and `query.skip;` respectively. Don't forget to use the semicolons though! ;) If you want to read up a bit, here's the link to the Parse docs where it is explained: [Parse Query Constraints](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-constraints/iOS)

Comment: Nicolas, you`re Awesome Dude!